# Why the Parent form is responding to short-cut keys of its Child form?

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForms: I have a MDI form and I have defined some short-cut keys for its menus for example "ALT+C" to open the Actions toolbar button. the problem is that if I open this child form inside the parent form but still I click my mouse somewhere inside the Parent form and press "ACLT+C" it is still responding to it and opening "Actions" menu of the child form. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Add a flag on your form

```
bool actionWindow = false
```

and then when the window opens set actionWindow to true.  In your listener check for actionWindow.  Then when the actionWindow closes, set the bool back to false.

try: in the child form put e.Handled = true; in the key press event.

Comment: I haven't done anything with MDI forms, but it would make sense to me that the behavior you are describing is correct.  Do you have to use MDI as the parent form?

Comment: we have upgraded this application from VB 6.0 and in VB 6.0 when I click "ALT+C" it does NOT open the Actions menu of the child form. so at code review he will say no, it is different from VB, why you did not white box it, etc...

Comment: Well, there are a lot of changes from vb6 to .net and like I said, I don't know much about MDI forms.  I would either not use mdi or use the hack above...I hope you find a good solution though.  Sorry I'm no help to you.

Comment: I changed my answer to include another option.  Set e.Handled = true to the key press/down event on your child form...be sure to turn keypreview on in the child also.

Comment: Stepping through the code it looks like the keypress goes to the parent first and then to the child...

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better solution out there, but a quick way would be to test if the form has focus. So in your child event handler, add the following at the top:

```
if ( this.MdiParent.ActiveControl.Name != this.Name )
{
    return;
}
```

Obviously this isn't preventing the event from firing, just preventing the subsequent code from running.

Edit: If there is no event handler for the menu item, the only other way I can think of to do this is to create handlers for the `Enter` and `Leave` events of the child form:

```
private void ChildForm_Leave( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    menuItem.Enabled = false;
}

private void ChildForm_Enter( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    menuItem.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Would that work?  The parent event fires before the child event.

Comment: Paul in what method, event handler, etc of my child form I should try your code?